# How to pass a column name in a chart title mixed with text in a custom plotting function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple plotting function

```
p<-function(a, x,y){ggplot(a, aes(a, y=y, x=x))+geom_point()}
```

I would like to add a title to the plotting function so that when I call the `function p(data, speed, distance)`, it will produce the following title: "Plot for speed and distance in Dataset data". How should I specify the title in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose df is your data frame.

```
p <- function(df, dfAsString, x, y) {
    ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(paste("Plot for", x, "and", y, "in Dataset", dfAsString, sep = " "))
}
```

The call of the function would be like `p(data, "data", "speed", "distance")`.

Comment: That won't work. I need the function to pass the value of a, x, and y in the title, so that next time if I call it with p(data1, rain, snow), these values will show in the title.

Comment: The answer has been reedited. This should solve your problem. You just need to paste a, x and y into your title argument. comment() allows you to pass the name of your data frame as a string.

Comment: This would be even more compact as a function if you explicitly pass the name of the data frame as a string. Maybe not best answer but should work.

Comment: That works. If there is no y, instead, y is expressed as the order of x from 1 to the last x as they appear, how should this work?

Comment: Even though this is already another problem, but what do you mean by the "order of x from 1 to the last x"? The index or the sorted order?

Comment: For example x=c(3, 5, 50, 34, 100), I want to use y=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), which is just the order of the numbers showing up in x.

Comment: You can simply replace y with seq_along(x). So it will be something like:  p <- function(df, dfAsString, x) { ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = seq_along(x)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste("Plot for", names(df)[i], "in DataSet", dfAsString, sep = " ")) } If x is the ith variable in your data frame.